# difference between two date times

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between two DateTimes. This is what I have:

```
if ((DateTime.Now.Date - TheUTCDateTime.Date).TotalMinutes > 180) 
{ 
      ValidObject = false;
}
```

Basically, I want to make sure that `TheUTCDateTime` is not more than 3 hours old. Is what I am doing the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to extract the date and maybe want to use `UtcNow` instead of `Now`.
You can also use `TimeSpan.FromHours` for the period:

```
if ((DateTime.UtcNow - TheUTCDateTime) > TimeSpan.FromHours(3))
```

or simply

```
ValidObject = (DateTime.UtcNow - TheUTCDateTime) <= TimeSpan.FromHours(3);
```

Comment: Should that be `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` and `TimeSpan.FromHours(3)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is ok, but you could improve it a little bit:

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - TheUTCDateTime.Date;
ValidObject = span.TotalHours <= 3;
```

Since you want to check the hours i have used `TotalHours`, i have used `DateTime.Now` instead of `Date` which truncates the time and i set it also to `true` whereas your code only sets it to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether `TheUTCDateTime` is older than 3 hours, you shouldn't be using the `.Date` property:

```
DateTime.UtcNow - TheUTCDateTime > TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
```